# Efficiently replace element if fullfil criteria in python

Tags: python, performance, replace

is there an efficient way to replace the element in a list.
For example, I want to replace "banana" to 3

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "banana", "banana"]

thislist[thislist == "banana"] = 3
```

By doing the above code, instead of banana, the 1st row which correspond to apple is being change to int 3.

It will be interesting if we can skip the use of FOR-LOOP

Really appreciate if someone can point the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) to get the index of the current item in your list:

```
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "banana", "banana"]

for i, fruit in enumerate(thislist):
    if fruit == 'banana':
        thislist[i] = 3
```

to explain what is happening in your code:

- `thislist == "banana"` is always `False` (comparing a `str` to a `list`)
- `thislist[False] == thislist[0]` (as `False == 0`)
- `thislist[0] = 3`: you only set the first element.

if you want to use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) you could to the same without a (explicit) `for` loop (not in plain python though...)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(["apple", "banana", "cherry", "banana", "banana"])
a[a == 'banana'] = 3
```

---

note that multiple replacements can be done with one `for` loop only:

```
repl = {'banana': 3, 'cherry': 5}

for i, fruit in enumerate(thislist):
    if fruit in repl:
        thislist[i] = repl[fruit]

print(thislist)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the for loop, you can try using the index() method of the list as follows:
    i = thislist.index('banana')
    thislist[i] = 3

Comment: Thanks for the respond, however it does not give the intended output. >> ['apple', 3, 'cherry', 'banana', 'banana']

Answer (score 1):

When we have `numpy` solution, we nearly always have a `pandas` version solution, just FYI.

```
import pandas as pd

thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "banana", "banana"]
newlist = pd.Series(thislist)
newlist[newlist=="banana"] = 3
print(newlist.tolist())
```

Output:

> ['apple', 3, 'cherry', 3, 3]